# How does comparison operator affect the outcome on dictionaries? Python 3.8

Tags: python, function, dictionary, operators

My case is slightly different to what I have seen, hence I am requesting some help to understand.

I was doing a question where I needed to check if some characters within a list were in a string.
I am still in the learning process so I thought in order to be able to account for any list and any
string input, I should convert them to dictionaries with the same value and compare the two, because I thought it would be easier. I was getting stuck at the end with the comparison part, but then when I compared the keys of the dictionaries with <=, it worked. Here is the code,

```
string = 'trleba' 
listofchar = ['a', 'b', 'e', 'l', 'r', 't']

def isItInIt(string, listofchar):

    letters = {}
    stringtoletter = {}

    for c in listofchar:
        if c not in letters:
            letters[c] = 1
        else:
            letters[c] += 1

    for e in list(string):
        if e not in stringtoletter:
            stringtoletter[e] = 1
        else:
            stringtoletter[e] += 1

    if stringtoletter.keys() <= letters.keys():
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(isItInIt(string, listofchar))
```

I apoligise if there may be a mistake in there, I had to change around some variable names.
My question basically is, how exactly does <= work here? I tried breaking it down and writing it out
but I just cant seem to grasp it. Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sets (and objects which resemble sets, like the results of `.keys()`) the `<=` operator means "subset or equal"; the mathematical notation would be: ⊆

The other comparisons `<`, `>=`, `>` similarly map to ⊂, ⊇ and ⊃ for sets.

Documentation for set: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset
Documentation for dict.keys(): https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects (paragraph starting "Key views are set-like")

Answer (score 0):

dict.keys() return [Dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) which is set-like objects.
<= is equivalent for [issubset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) set method.